# Riesz representation for an infinite-dimensional space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

Suppose $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach algebra (hence not locally compact).

Does there exist any sort of Riesz representation theorem that says something about elements of $C(X)^*$?

Comment: How do you make $C(X)$ a Banach space?

Comment: I didn't say $C(X)$ is a Banach space. 

Comment: Is $C(X)$ suppose to be a Banach space?


Comment: Which norm do you take to get a Banach space? Or what do you mean by $C(X)$? If it is the continuous functions on $X$, then without compactness they are not bounded.

Comment: No, it does not have to be a Banach space. Which topology do you take then?

Comment: $C(X)$ can be given a topology (most likely not a normable), but I don't want to specify one because that is part of the question. I am asking if there is some sort of Riesz representation theorem for an infinite-dimensional space $X$ where $C(X)$ has some nontrivial topology? 

Comment: Where are you using the Banach **algebra** structure on $X$? As it stands, I think this question is far too vague. What is your intended substitute for "Radon measure"?

Comment: @Yemon, You are misunderstanding the question. I give you a Banach algebra $X$ that is infinite dimensional. I am asking for a topology on $C(X)$ and a characterization of its dual. I am asking if anyone has seen such sort of theorem. The focus is the infinite-dimensionality of $X$. Either you have seen a Riesz-type theorem for infinite-dimensional spaces or not. If you don't like $X$ being an algebra, assume it's just a Banach space, or assume it's just a topological vector space.

Comment: @Banach: I am not misunderstanding the question. My point is that it is very odd to be purely considering the set of continuous complex-valued functions on $X$, it means that there is a lot of a structure that you are not using, and suggests that you should not really be looking at the dual of all of $C(X)$ but instead at the dual of something much smaller. Your initial emphasis on $X$ being a Banach algebra seems misguided and is most likely **irrelevant** to any characterization of the TVS dual of $C(X)$ that you seem to desire

Comment: For instance, have you tried looking for versions of Riesz representation for $C(X)$ where $X$ is just a metrizable non LCH space? Or is the linear/affine structure of $X$ supposed to be important?

Comment: @Yemon, which smaller space do you suggest to consider instead of $C(X)$? Do you know of a reference for Riesz representation for $C(X)$ where $X$ is a metrizable non LCH space?

Answer (score 3):

I would guess "the" natural topology on this space should be that of uniform convergence on compact subsets. Since a function on $X$ is continuous iff it its restrictions on compact subsets are continuous, $C(X)$ is actually the projective limit of $C(K), K \subset X$, $K$ compact. Which means that its dual should be the inductive limit of spaces of measures on $K$, that is, the space of measures with compact support.

Comment:  What does it mean that $C(X)$ is the projective limit of $C(K)$? Does this require X to be a countable union of compact sets?

Comment: @Banach: Of course not. A projective limit may be defined for any directed family, which may be neither countable nor linearly ordered. Intuitively, this means that a continuous function "is" a collection of functions on compact subsets that fit together nicely, and the topology on $C(X)$ is generated by taking these restrictions. For precise definitions, see, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology.

Comment: According to my topology book, there is a restriction. The statement, "a function on X is continuous iff its restrictions on compact subsets are continuous" requires X to be compactly generated. However, in my case X is compactly generated.

Comment: I looked up projective limit, but I don't see why $C(X)$ is the projective limit of $C(K)$. Would you please indicate what are the coordinate spaces and the bonding maps in the inverse limit?

Comment: The set of compact subsets is naturally ordered by inclusion. To each compact $K$ we have to associate a space - namely, $C(K)$ - and for each pair $K_1 \subset K_2$ we need a map $C(K_2) \to C(K_1)$ - in this case it is the restriction map.